# ProcessBuilder on OSX

Tags: java, macos, runtime.exec, processbuilder

I am able to successfully execute this on windows:

`builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "nmap " + ipRange, "&cd");`

But this on OSX fails:

`builder = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/local/bin/nmap", ipRange);`

With the error:

"Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-03-22 09:51 PDT

Invalid host expression: 127.0.0.1 -p T:80 -- colons only allowed in IPv6 addresses, and then you need the -6 switch

QUITTING!"

What is the correct way to create that ProcessBuilder for OSX?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you are trying to pass two separate parameters as one String in `ipRange`. The ProcessBuilder probably wraps the ipRange String with quotes and messes up the command syntax. You need to add all parameters separately

Not like this:

```
new ProcessBuilder("/usr/local/bin/nmap", "-foo foo -bar bar");
```

but like this:

```
new ProcessBuilder("/usr/local/bin/nmap", "-foo", "foo", "-bar", "bar");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved it. Any ideas why it's not an issue on windows?

Comment: Basically, if your previous version worked on windows, your lucky. But ProcessBuilder is only intended to work if you specify each parameter separately. The docs are unfortunately not specific about this.