# Cant get the wkhtmltopdf attributes to work with in java code

Tags: java, process, wkhtmltopdf, processbuilder

I am using wkhtmltopdf converter to convert html file to pdf. It works fine except that the output does not fit the page in pdf. Using --zoom 2 fixes the problem at command line but with using the same in my code doesnt do anything. below is my code.

```
String wkhtmltopdf = "C:/Program Files (x86)/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe ";
String switches = " --zoom 2 ";

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(wkhtmltopdf, switches, f.getAbsolutePath(), pdfFileName);

Process process = pb.start();
```

In command line this works just fine.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf>wkhtmltopdf.exe --zoom 2 C:\Users\D
esktop\eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\temphtml1.htm C:\Users\Desktop\temp\test.pdf
Loading pages (1/6)
Counting pages (2/6)
Resolving links (4/6)
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

Could someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When i had similar problems, using `disable-smart-shrinking` did the trick for me. You may have to set all `margin-*` to `0`.

Comment: I get Unknown long argument --zoom 1.5 --margin-right 0 --margin-top 0 --margin-bottom 0 --margin-left 0. why does it work in the command line not in my code?

Comment: disable-smart-shrinking doesnt work, zoom does. But not in my code. I am guessing it has to do with how the parameters are passed to the processbuilder. Any thoughts?

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/213217/convert-html-to-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Runtime in place of processBuilder fixed it. I still dont know why "--zoom 2" is not excepted as a parameter in processBuilder. However, below is the working code.

```java
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = rt.exec(
  "C:/Program Files (x86)/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe --zoom 2 " 
    + temphtmlfile.getAbsolutePath()
    + " " 
    + filePdf.getAbsolutePath()) ;
```

Answer (score 4):

As noted in [ProcessBuilder on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826909/processbuilder-on-osx), you need to pass each argument groups as separate strings. So instead of passing "--zoom 2" you would pass ["--zoom", "2"].

Comment: Thanks for sharing the trick, btw which is better, to pass the arguments as an array or as a long string like in the accepted answer?

Comment: My oppinion is that writing out a string is sloppy because of how immutable and error prone (and illegible) it is.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the parameter `--cookie <name> <value>` and I figured out that, using `ProcessBuilder` I had to pass 3 separated String values `--cookie, <name>, <value>`.

You would have to replace

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(wkhtmltopdf, switches, f.getAbsolutePath(), pdfFileName);
```

by

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(wkhtmltopdf, "--zoom", "2", f.getAbsolutePath(), pdfFileName);
```

---

Note that ProcessBuilder has a more convenient constructor that can take a `List<String>`